# How to convert 12 hours format to 24 hours format in swift?

Tags: swift

```
func utcToLocal(dateStr: String) -> String? {
    let isCurrentDevice12HoursFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)?.range(of: "a") != nil
    let isDateStr12HoursFormat = dateStr.last == "M"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: isDateStr12HoursFormat ? "en_US_POSIX" : "en_UK_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = isDateStr12HoursFormat ? "yyyy-MM-dd' 'h:mm:ss a" : "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = isCurrentDevice12HoursFormat ? "yyyy-MM-dd' 'h:mm:ss a" : "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return nil
}
```

*I wrote this function to display the time properly when my phone is in the 12 hour zone. But when I print the clock in the function below, the clock part returns empty. What could be the reason for this?*

```
 private func notify(event: NewScheduledEvent) {
        let localDate = utcToLocal(dateStr: event.dateString.description.components(separatedBy: "+").first?.trimTrailingWhitespaces() ?? "") ?? ""
        let desc = CustomEventType.newScheduledEvent.description.replacingOccurrences(of: "%s", with: localDate)
        notifyUserViaBottomSheet(eventType: CustomEventType.newScheduledEvent,
                                 description: desc,
                                 confirmButtonTitle: "ok".localized)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the date parsing was successful? Print the dateStr and add it to your post

Comment: Note that escaping the space is pointless and I have never heard of en_UK_POSIX. You should use only en_US_POSIX